# is it possible to show contact number of current logged in user when artifact is created in tuleap

Tags: artifact, tuleap

We are using the Tuleap 7.0 for Project management. We have a new requirement that we need to show the contact number of current logged in user when a artifact is submitted either in a separate field or in the same field (submitted by). Is it possible to show or what type of code change has to be done, to retrieve the current logged in user information when artifact is created. Kindly do needful.

Answer (score 0):

That's not easy. There are two main steps: one surrounding the user; the other surrounding the artifact.

First you would need to edit PFUser.class.php to add the property to the user object. You would also probably need to create a forgeupgrade script (database upgrade) so that you could save and modify the property. Obviously the UI and scripts that manage the CRUD of a user would also need changing.

Next, you would need to create a new type of class that extends TrackerformElementField, make that type available for use in the Tracker Field administration and set its value to the user's contact number.

Unfortunately, any of these modifications, if not done carefully, can have important side-effects. If you want to write your code and have it reviewed by the community, you can go through gerrit.tuleap.net and read the [developer guide](http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/developer-guide/dev-setup.html#debug-profiling)